# Raster cells with no data being generated by las2dem?

Tags: raster, dem, lidar, nodata, lastools

Anyone has an idea where these lines (with no elevation data) come from? They are generated while using the `las2dem` tool from LAStools.

What needs to be done to avoid this? The raw data (.las file) does not contain data with value 0.

[image]

Comment: Is this a licenced copy of lastools?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out (got the hint from the user forum on rapidlasso.com): like mdsumner indicated with his/her question, it is a problem of the open source lastools version (LGPL 2.1). With the licenced model these bands will not be generated.